# SQLite3 Select where string query

Tags: php, sqlite

I can't figure out simplest thing. Tried various things, but no success. I want to simply select from table a Team with particular name. This code will return me just a header of the table, and won't print anything, as though my query is empty.

I've tried changing quotes differently but it would either give me an error or print nothing.

```
SELECT * from League where Name='AS Roma'

SELECT * from League where Name=AS Roma

SELECT * from League where Name="AS Roma"
```

Does anyone has any clue?

```
     $db = new SQLite3('test.db');
     $results = $db->query('SELECT * from League where Name="AS Roma"');

     echo "<table border='1'>";
     echo "<tr>";
     echo "<th>Position</th><th>Club Name</th><th>G</th><th>W</th><th>D</th><th>L</th><th>GF</th><th>GA</th><th>P</th>";
     echo "</tr>";

     while ($row = $results->fetchArray()) {
       echo "<tr>";
       echo "<td>", $row[0], "</td><td>", $row[1],"</td>", "<td>", $row[2], "</td><td>", $row[3],"</td>","<td>", $row[4], "</td><td>", $row[5],"</td>", "<td>", $row[6], "</td><td>", $row[7],"</td>",  "<td>", $row[8], "</td>";
       echo "</tr>";
     }
     echo "</table>";
     echo '<br>';
```

Comment: Are you sure there's a field in your database with the value `"AS Roma"`?  A query returning 0 rows isn't an error.

Comment: Yes off course, that's not the issue. I know since it returns empty, that means in cant find it, but it's there. i thought that i have a syntax problem

Comment: if I type directly in the SQLite Manager following SELECT * FROM League where Name='SS Lazio', it would still give me an empty thing, but it's there

Comment: What does SELECT * FROM League; print?

Comment: An entire Table with it's contents

Comment: Are you sure the team names don't have spaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using SQLite3::prepare.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * from League where Name LIKE :name');
$stmt->bindValue(':name', 'AS Roma', SQLITE3_TEXT);

$result = $stmt->execute();
while ( $row = $result->fetchArray()) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I dont know why, but the same problem occurs. It prints table's header only, no actual data

Answer (score -2):

You might want to try to swap your quotes and use backticks.

Before:

```
$results = $db->query('SELECT * from League where Name="AS Roma"');
```

After:

```
$results = $db->query("SELECT * from League where Name=`AS Roma`");
```

Comment: tried it => QLite3::query(): Unable to prepare statement: 1, no such column: AS Roma

Comment: Backticks denote a *field name*; quotes denote a *string*.